# Understanding type synonyms and parameterized type synonyms in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I have the follow type:

```
type Name = String

type Assignation a = Name -> a
```

and the following function declaration:

```
actAsig :: Assignation a -> Name -> a -> Assignation a
```

This function should return a new `Assignation` that returns the newly assigned value for the supplied `Name`, and the previously-assigned values for other `Name`s.

Comment: The type of `actAsig` looks pretty strange (why does it take an argument of type `a`?), and I'm having trouble understanding the language of the question.

Comment: @dfeuer It looks to me like they're using (String -> a) like a map, and this actAsig is supposed to be like "put", adding a new mapping to the front. eg `actAsig f k v x | x == k = v | otherwise = f x`.

Comment: `put :: (Name, a) -> Assignation a -> Assignation a` would make the meaning just so much more obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cactus has already brilliantly addressed any questions you might have had about the implementation of the `actAsig` function, however, I feel that the questions in the title of the post have been left unaddressed.

---

First of all, Haskell has both a value level language ([Object Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_language)) and a type level language ([Metalanguage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalanguage)). They are both powerful but not normally equally powerful, at least not for the same things. However, some things work on both sides, such as constants, variables and functions.

A type level constant is:

```
type Name = String
```

— this is normally called a "type alias": it means `Name` is made in (almost) all respects equivalent to `String`. This *doesn't* introduce a new type, only a new name for an existing type. This is useful for making the intent in your code more readable if you don't want to introduce an actual new type with `data` or `newtype`, in which case you'd be introducing a new set of values that need to be mapped from and to existing sets of values (i.e. types). Therefore, `type` is just a thing of convenience, if you will, not a measure of safety, which is instead what `data` and `newtype` are for.

However, the Haskell type level language also supports functions, i.e. mappings from 1 or more types to some existing type. You could consider this to be parametric aliasing, so to speak.

```
type Assignation a = Name -> a
```

This creates a type function called `Assignation` with a parameter `a`. Given a type `a`, it returns some type, in this case the type `Name -> a`. So `Assignation Int` returns `Name -> Int`; `Assignation Person` returns `Name -> Person` and so on. Note that sometimes type functions don't make use of one or more of their parameters, just like value level functions:

```
type Empty a = ()
```

If we combine this new knowledge, we can start thinking in terms of type level evaluation/reduction, i.e. evaluation that only takes places within the borders of type signatures, type functions, type class constraint computations etc.

Let's apply this to the type signature of `actAsig`, step by step:

```
Assignation a -> Name   -> a -> Assignation a
Assignation a -> String -> a -> Assignation a
(Name -> a)   -> String -> a -> (Name -> a)
(String -> a) -> String -> a -> (String -> a)
```

So the higher order function type you are seeing on the last line above, is the actual type of `actAsig`, all abstractions eliminated/reduced away.

In human language terms, the signature descirbes a function that

1. takes a function `f` that maps strings to values of some type `a`.
2. takes a string
3. takes a value of that type `a`
4. returns a new function of the same type as `f`.

So in a way, `actAsig` processes functions: it takes functions and returns new, possibly modified functions.

---

Furthermore, Haskell also has (somewhat basic) means of fuzzying the line between typelevel and value-level, by making computations in the type realm involve references (dependencies) into the value level, but that's outside of the scope of this post, and would lead us into the world of [Dependent Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) and [Dependent Type Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory#Dependent_types).

Comment: Thanks for the explain, this was really useful to understand the type behavior in this context. Very clear and consistent the answer.

Answer (score 7):

The specification of `actAsig`, if I understand right, is that given

```
assignation1 :: Assignation a
newName :: Name
newValue :: a

assignation2 = actAsig assignation1 newName newValue
```

The requirement on `assignation2` is that

```
assignation2 name = if name == newName then newValue else assignation1 name
```

So, you can write it exactly like that:

```
actAsig :: Assignation a -> Name -> a -> Assignation a
actAsig assignation1 newName newValue name = 
    if name == newName then newValue else assignation1 name
```

Comment: @ErikAllik: Is there a flag to put it on the "improvement" queue?

Comment: I was just puzzled to find out what the OP actually wants to know... I'm fine with the question as is...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, lament can't set two answers like the good one, because both explain my issue.